# DKIM for Plesk with remotely managed DNS

Tags: dns, plesk, dkim, spf, amazon-route53

Our primary domains DNS is managed over at Amazon Route 53, and so in Plesk (11.x) I've turned DNS off. The problem is that I want to begin using DMARC which requires both SPF and DKIM txt records to be working.

Our SPF record works great since all I'm doing is limiting it to our MX...

```
"v=spf1 mx -all"
```

I've set up the monitoring DMARC string as follows so it's only sending reports but not actively filtering yet...

```
"v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:monitoringemail@ourdomain.tld"
```

The problem is that Plesk would normally automatically add the DKIM related TXT record to the domains DNS with the appropriate public key, but since our DNS is switched off for the domain that record is inaccessible, i.e. I can't see it in plesk so I can replicate it at Amazon Route 53.

For the time being so we're not being filtered, I've switched off DKIM support in Plesk again, but once I turn it back on in Plesk, is it possible to find the public key somewhere other than in the DNS records area in Plesk? If so, how would I go about using that info to create the appropriate DKIM TXT DNS string?

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT: It seems I've confused DomainKeys and DKIM for the same thing, and that Plesk 11 doesn't directly support DKIM, so my new question is, how does one go about generating a DKIM record on a plesk system so that messages are tagged, and then secondly, how do I translate that into a DNS TXT record to match it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regrading the part

> It seems I've confused DomainKeys and DKIM for the same thing, and that Plesk 11 doesn't directly support DKIM, so my new question is, how does one go about generating a DKIM record on a plesk system

I did the same thing for MandrillApp using plesk. Just enter the DNS setting section and select "add new record" Choose type TXT and enter the given DKIM values.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is, isn't the server supposed to tag all outbound messages with some part of a public key that is supposed to match the DKIM one specified in the DNS record?  I can certainly create the DNS entry, but how do I get the server to include the necessary headers in the messages themselves?